# What is the proper way to escape a URL for URLConnection.getInputStream()?

Tags: java, android, urlconnection

I'm having a really bizarre problem with URLConnection.getInputStream() when I have a space (' ') in the query string portion of a URI. Specifically, I have one URL that works and another that does not, when I think they should both fail or both succeed, additionally, its every time.

Working URL: http://minneapolis.craigslist.ca/search/sss?catAbb=sss&query=iPhone+sprint&sort=date&srchType=A&format=rss
Failed URL (exception below) : http://winnipeg.craigslist.ca/search/sss?catAbb=sss&query=iPhone+sprint&sort=date&srchType=A&format=rss

conn.getInputStream() throws the IO exception: "Illegal character in query at index 67: http://winnipeg.en.craigslist.ca/search/sss?catAbb=sss&query=iPhone sprint two&sort=date&srchType=A&format=rss"

It appears openConnection can't get the space (which I've already replaced with a '+' as I'd expect to have to with a 'URL', I've also tried '%20' with the same results.

Additionally, URL.toString() reports the URLS as I printed above, with the '+' not the space.

Code is as follows, searchUrl is a 'URL' instance.

```
        URLConnection conn = null;
        conn = searchUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
        conn.setUseCaches(true);
        conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);

        ByteArrayOutputStream oStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream istream = conn.getInputStream();
        int numBytesRead, numBytesWritten = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
        while ((numBytesRead = istream.read(buffer, 0, 8 * 1024)) > 0) {
            oStream.write(buffer, numBytesWritten, numBytesRead);
            numBytesWritten += numBytesRead;
        }
```

Any ideas on where to deal with this? I'm about to pitch URLConnection and go another route...

Thanks
Kenny.

Comment: I think you have made a mistake in your question.  The URLs both search for "iPhone sprint" but the error message says that the URL is "iPhone sprint two".  Please correct the question with the **real** URLs and the **real** error message.

Comment: The problem was hidden in that the " " was in the redirect URL NOT in the one that I originally encoded.  I intercepted the redirect and encoded the parameters in the result.  So essentially the problem was with the web site I was accessing creating a redirect that wasn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your question (see my comment).

However, the fundamental problem here is that a URL with a space character in the query part is not a legal URL ... not withstanding that a typical web browser will accept it.  The exception is therefore correct.

Your example URLs seem to show that the space is escaped with a '+'.  This is HTML form escaping not proper URL escaping.  You seem to be saying that you get the same result is you use `%20` ... which would be correct escaping.

So my theory is that you are actually passing this URL to your code via a route that is removing the escapes ... not-withstanding what your traceprints seem to be telling you.  (If I could see an SSCE we'd be able to test this theory ...)

---

FWIW, fixing the problem by calling UrlEncoder.encode as some of the other answers have suggested is a bad idea.  The problem is that it is likely to "encode" other characters that shouldn't be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

The URL itself is best encoded with new URI(null, url, null).toASCIIString().

Each key and value in the query string can be separately encoded with URLEncoder.encode(). According to [RFC 2936](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) this isn't correct and the whole thing should be encoded as for the URL itself, but I've never seen it fail.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try `URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8")`

Following is the example:

Replace

```
String url = "http://somesite.com/page?user=" + user;
```

with

```
String url = "http://somesite.com/page?user="
+ URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String url= URLEncoder.encode("your URL without http or your query string part here");
URL searchUrl = new URL("http://" + url);
URLConnection conn = null;
conn = searchUrl.openConnection();
```